# Вызов функции правильно понял?

Tags: javascript

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'hello',
  work(b) {
  alert( this.name + ' ' + b ); // произвольная функция или метод
},
};


function spy(func){

  return function f(){

    // return func.call(this, ...arguments); // this будет сылаться на объект obj ?
    return func(); // func будет функция; this будет вызываться на глобальный объект ?
    
  }; 

}


obj.work = spy(obj.work );

obj.work(1);
```

1. Элемент списка

```js
function f(x) {
  alert(x);
}

function delay(f, ms) {

  let getThis = this;
   
    let h = {
      name: 'hello',
      say() {
       alert(getThis.name)
      }
    }
     h.say()
   return  setTimeout( () => {
      f(1)
    })
   
}

f = delay(f, 1000);

f(1)
```

1. В переменную **getThis**  записываем **this** т.к. **delay**  вызывается в глобальном контексте в **this** будет ссылка на глобальный контекст ?
2. Переменную  **getThis** добавляем в метод объекта **h** переменная

```js
function work(a, b) {
  console.log( a + b );
}

function spy(func){

   function f(...d){
    f.calls.push(d);

    return func.call(this, ...arguments);
    
  }; 

  f.calls = [];
  return f
}


work = spy(work);

work(1, 2);
work(4, 5);


for (let args of work.calls) {
  alert( 'call:' + args.join() ); // "call:1,2", "call:4,5"
}
```

**getThis** будет глобальный ?

```js
function work(a, b) {
  console.log( a + b ); // произвольная функция или метод
}

function spy(func){

   function f(...d){
    f.calls.push(d);

    return func.call(this, ...arguments);
    
  }; 

  f.calls = [];
  return f
}


work = spy(work);

work(1, 2);
work(4, 5);


for (let args of work.calls) {
  alert( 'call:' + args.join() ); // "call:1,2", "call:4,5"
}
```

1. эта функция **func.call(this, ...arguments)**  *this* будет ссылаться на  глобальный объект ?

Comment: что по вашему значит _функция вызывается как глобальный объект_?

Comment: @ThisMan правильнее сказать будет func.call(this, ...arguments) ; this будет ссылаться на глобальный объект ?

Comment: `this` будет ссылаться на того, кто вызвал функцию `f`. В вашем примере `work === f`, а `work` вызывается в глобальном контексте, а значит `this === глобальный объект`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko можно проще func вызывается как функция значит this глобальный объект ?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. `Func` вызывается через `call` и туда первым параметром идет `this`. Данный `this` будет зависеть от того, как вызван `work`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko 1) скажите в первый блок кода выполняется d(); в переменную копируем this 2) и переменную добавляем в метод объекта this будет глобальный ?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Если убрать call  то func будет вызываться как функция значит глобальный объект ?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko  если перед **work** будет стоять объект **obj.work() **  то** this ** будет вызываться как метод объекта значит получит доступ к информации объекта, а у **func  **убрать  ** call** то у ** func  this ** будет ссылаться на глобальный объект

Comment: Вы поменяли вопрос, у теперь у вас там три вопроса и вообще ничего не понятно, чего вы хотите.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko вечером добавлю код ... спасибо за внимание

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko  посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: У вас в вопросе 5 вопросов. Вы что хотите узнать? Могу ответить только так.  да, да - но не правильная формулировка, да, да, да.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko  правильно понял что надо задать 5 вопросов ?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko1) я хочу узнать как ведет себя this когда передается в другую функцию,2)  Что происходит this когда вызывается функция с this 
 в другой функции 3)  Как ведет себя this  когда мы в другой функции, объекте вызываем this  через call или apply 4) что происходит когда this  сохраняется в переменную, а потом куда-нибудь эта переменная передается и т.д.

Comment: Мне кажется, данный ресурс немного не про это. Вы сможете найти ответы на ваши вопросы в любой книге, посвященный js.  Например, [this](http://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods) и [call\apply](http://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply)

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko ясно, спасибо за внимание ...